# webapp directories should have the directory name as owner and group?

Tags: linux, webserver, ubuntu, wordpress

Some programmer told me that my usual way to change ownership and permissions to my webapp dirs isn't good:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/* -R
```

He told me that this could result in a state when malicious CMS modules affect molecularity of adjacent webapps with the same owner.

I think that this is a good solution

**1)** When I create a new webapp:

```
sudo chown -R ${domain}:${domain} ${domain}/*
```

**2)** When I change an existing webapp:

```
cd /var/www/html && sudo chown -R $<domain.tld>:<domain.tld> domain.tld/*
```

### My qeustion

My question is comprised of the following two questions:

1. Was the programmer right?
2. How should I add user in a safe user to give it as owner and group? (not sure if to pick `useradd`/`adduser` and with what permissions, for that purpose.

Comment: Worth noting if the application does not need ownership or write access to a file then it shouldn't be granted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the suggestion is particularly to have the same value as the user and group as the directory name, but rather to have a single user/group for each directory.

If you use www-data for all cases, then a compromise of a single site (or malicious site owner in the case of shared hosting) can easily read & write files into the other site directories.

Having multiple users (one per site, for example) mitigates the damage in a compromise.  Typically, you'd want `www-data` for the group (and group readable, but not writable permissions) so your webserver can read all of the static files, and to run a per-user instance of your application server.  (For example, one php-fcgi or python gunicorn instance running as each site owner, for the appropriate language.)

You can use `adduser`, but I would use both the `--disabled-password` and `--disabled-login` flags to ensure that the new user does not also become an attack vector!

Comment: Indeed, the suggestion is as you describe it. I just think that make the owner identical to site dir is minimal and likely to be efficient.